# How to control the select box when I add new one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) and I have the group of inputs that user add it as he wants, but just the first select box runs ok with the plugin but others inputs don't

HTML code:

```
<div id="products-color">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="color_id" style="width:100%">
            @foreach($colors as $color)
                <option value="{{ $color->id }}">{{ $color->name }}</option>
            @endforeach 
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-tiffany" onclick="addColorOption()">Add New </button>
```

js code:

```
 function addColorOption() {
    var color = `
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="color_id" style="width:100%">
                @foreach($colors as $color)
                    <option value="{{ $color->id }}">{{ $color->name }}</option>
                @endforeach 
            </select>
        </div>
    `;
    $('#products-color').append(color);
}
```

bootstrap select plugin:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

That's means just the first select box runs with the plugin but when I add a new select box by `add new` button the plugin does not work

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle for your issue ?

Comment: @Prince believe me, don't know how!

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? Are you getting any error or how is it behaving ? Can you update the error in question ?

Comment: @Prince no there is no error in anywhere but when I add new select box by the new button, the new select box does not work with the plugin !

Comment: Can you try putting this line $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); or $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
inside the addColorOption as last line ?

Comment: @Prince worrrrrrkedddd !!! thank you, man!!

Comment: Great, let me add my answer.

Comment: @Prince pls with explaining the issue

Comment: What is the “@foreach” the string? You need to post a fiddle of this, I can see how this would work. You might want to try adding the select using the native JavaScript DOM API. E.g. let select - document.createElement(‘select’) etc.

Comment: @rhys_stubbs it's Laravel blade engine means foreach in php

Comment: @Musa Added my answer below.

Comment: @Musa Right I see, that will only be evaluated once and not dynamically run after the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();` as last line of `addColorOptions` method to initialize the newly added select.

As we are adding a `bootstrap-select` dynamically, we need to initialize them after creating them. You can find the documentation [bootstrap-select here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

Answer (score 0):

The `select` elements generated with `addColorOption()` should each have a unique `name` value, not the same as your original element. You could generate a number based on the number of existing selects each time and append it to the name of the new element.

Answer (score 0):

when everything is working fine and just dynamically added select inputs not rendering as expected

```
 function addColorOption() {
    var color = `
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="color_id" style="width:100%">
                @foreach($colors as $color)
                    <option value="{{ $color->id }}">{{ $color->name }}</option>
                @endforeach 
            </select>
        </div>
    `;
    $('#products-color').append(color);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();  //just adding it here will do
}
``
```